# Asymptotic series expansions for Inverse Laplace Transform?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

It appears that the following function, defined in terms of Inverse Laplace Transform, has a compact approximation

$$g(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{\frac{s}{2}+\frac{5 \sqrt{s}}{\sqrt{6} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt{s}}\right)}}\right]\approx 0.434 t^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

How could I have obtained this with Mathematica?

In particular, I'm wondering if there's built-in functionality to let me write $f(s)=\mathcal{L}[g(t)]$, the arctan expression above, as the following series, for $0<\lambda_0<\lambda_1<\ldots$ and $\lambda_0=\frac{1}{2}$

$$f(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{s^{\lambda_n}}$$

because that gives the following power series representation of $g(t)$

$$g(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n t^{\lambda_n-1}}{\Gamma(\lambda_n)}$$

Tried `Limit[InverseLaplaceTransform[...]]` and `Asymptotic[InverseLaplaceTransform[...]]` with no luck.

[image]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
g = 1/(s/2 + (5 Sqrt[s])/(Sqrt[6] ArcTan[Sqrt[2/3]/Sqrt[s]]));
plot1 = DiscretePlot[
   InverseLaplaceTransform[g, s, t], {t, 0., 100, 10}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"g(t)"}];
plot2 = Plot[0.434 t^(-1/2), {t, 0, 100}, 
   PlotLegends -> {" 0.434 t^(-1/2)"}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

Related mathoverflow [discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446547/7655) and mathematica.SE [discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284839/tricky-inverselaplacetransform-problem)

Comment: Something strange. In 13.2.1 on Windows 10 `g = 1/(s/2 + (5 Sqrt[s])/(Sqrt[6] ArcTan[Sqrt[2/3]/Sqrt[s]]));InverseLaplaceTransform[g, s, t]` produces a mixture of `t` and `s`: `1/t3 (-((
    5 E^(-2 t/3)
      Log[1/8 (-2 - 3 s)])/(-10 + Log[1/8 (-2 - 3 s)])^2) - (
   10 (-1 + E^(-2 t/3)))/(10 + Log[8] - Log[-2 - 3 s])^2 + (
   5 E^(-2 t/3)
     Log[1/8 (-2 - 3 s)])/(10 + Log[8] - Log[-2 - 3 s])^2 - (
   E^(-2 t/3)
     Log[1/8 (-2 - 3 s)]^2)/(10 + Log[8] - 
     Log[-2 - 3 s])^2 + ((-1 + E^(-2 t/3)) Log[
     1/8 (-2 - 3 s)]^2)/(10 + Log[8] - Log[-2 - 3 s])^2`.

Comment: @user64494 this also happens with simpler expressions that can be inverted exactly, some workaounds here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284437/inverselaplacetransform-involving-an-arctan

Comment: YaroslavBulatov (@ does not work.): Sorry, this is your duty.

Comment: @user64494 I suspect there's no way to invert this Laplace transform symbolically, even after fixing that issue (related discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/284839/tricky-inverselaplacetransform-problem)), so some asymptotic approach is needed here . @ doesn't work because author is automatically notified of comments on their posts

Comment: I assume that you are looking for an approximation whose accuracy increases for large t

Comment: You wrote "so some asymptotic approach is needed here". This is neither math nor Mathematica, but speculations.  I vote to close the question.

Comment: Unfortunately,`Asymptotic[
 Inactive[InverseLaplaceTransform][
  1/(s/2 + (5 Sqrt[s])/(Sqrt[6] ArcTan[Sqrt[2/3]/Sqrt[s]])), s, t], 
 t -> Infinity]` fails in 13.2.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: This page provides a list of methods: https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.4.

Comment: Asking ChatGPT for a list of methods for this case you will find similar answers plus the Tauberian method provided by the answer in your math overflow link (which seems to also be here in a more general scenaro: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_Tauberian_theorem). ChatGPT is not good at performing math but it can be useful for finding relevant aspects of math as shown here if I recall correctly: https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.13867

Comment: Also maybe consider the more generic methods for asymptotic analysis of intergrals https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the trick to get that expansion was to switch order of Laplace Transform and Asymptotic, and do asymptotic around 0

```
g = 1/(s/2 + (5 Sqrt[s])/(Sqrt[6] ArcTan[Sqrt[2/3]/Sqrt[s]]));
InverseLaplaceTransform[Asymptotic[g, s -> 0], s, t] (* Sqrt[(3 \[Pi])/2]/(5 Sqrt[t]) *)
```

The reason this works is because asymptotics of $t\to \infty$ in time domain corresponds to asymptotics of $s\to 0$ in Laplace domain, so this an gives 2 ways of getting series expansion for the same regime.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f = (Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Erf[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t]])/(2 Sqrt[t]);

isTimeDomain[expr_] := MemberQ[Variables@expr, t];
laplace[expr_] := If[isTimeDomain[expr],
   Distribute[LaplaceTransform[expr, t, s]],
   Distribute[InverseLaplaceTransform[expr, s, t]]];

asymp[expr_] := If[isTimeDomain[expr],
  Asymptotic[expr, {t, \[Infinity], 2}],
  Asymptotic[expr, {s, 0, 2}]
  ]

vals = Map[
   TraditionalForm, {{f, laplace@f}, {asymp@f, 
     asymp@laplace@f}, {laplace@asymp@laplace@f, 
     laplace@asymp@f}}, {2}];
TableForm[vals, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"original", "asymptotic1", 
    "asymptotic2"}, {"time domain", "laplace domain"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: All that is built on the sand. Such type answers are not a good practice though `N[Sqrt[(3 \[Pi])/2]/5]` results in `0.434161` which is  close  to `0.434`.

Comment: Why the asymptotic as `s` tends to zero works for the asymptotic as `t` tends to infinity?

Comment: [Tauberian type theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy–Littlewood_Tauberian_theorem) give the relation between `t` to zero and `s` to infinity in your notations.

Comment: It should be added these theorems are about Laplace transform, not about inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: @user64494 right, you can compute asymptotics in one domain and convert to another. Numerically, should be the same, but there are intriguing differences in algebraic expressions obtained. Consider `f = (Sqrt[\[Pi]/2] Erf[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[t]])/(2 Sqrt[t]);
g = LaplaceTransform[f, t, s];
Asymptotic[f, {t, \[Infinity], 3}]
Asymptotic[g, {s, 0, 3}]`

Comment: Sorry,  I  don't find "you can compute asymptotics in one domain and convert to another" any argument. Maybe, some (unknown to me) Tauberian theorem stands behind your speculation.

Comment: @user64494 Theorem 2.7 and 2.8 of Cohen's Inverse Laplace [book](https://www.siirt.edu.tr/dosya/personel/laplace-siirt-2019320222328704.pdf) show how Puiseux series in Laplace domain correspond to infinite series in time domain. There's also [Watson's Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma)